# Can phase change/transition occur during adiabatic free expansion?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, adiabatic

If I am not mistaken, during [phase change/transition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_transition) the internal energy is also changing, but for adiabatic free expansion the change in internal energy is zero. So if phase change can occur during adiabatic free expansion, how is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Classically speaking, even in an adiabatic system some of the particles are certainly welcome to transfer their energy to other particles in that same system, allowing them to experience a phase change. A series of such partial changes could, in theory, allow all the particles to eventually change their phase while the system remains adiabatic--as long as each internal energy transfer was adiabatic. Also, quantum mechanically speaking, if the system is observed only at the beginning and at the end of a global phase change, then a global phase change is allowed without an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

During a phase change, the internal energy is also changing if the temperature and pressure are constant.  In an adiabatic free expansion involving a phase change, the temperature and (of course) pressure are not constant.